# How to automatically Save and Exit out of a worksheet after a set amount of time? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make an open worksheet close itself if there is no activity on it for more than 5 minutes?

So for example: I work on a worksheet for a while then walk away for 20 minutes with said sheet open. Someone on the network requires to access the sheet but can't because I'm on it.

I want it so that after me being away from my desk for more than 5 minutes the sheet will save itself and close out said sheet.

Is this possible? If so how? I can find scripts to show how to save and close a sheet, but I've yet to find one that uses a timer...

Comment: The answer is posted here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/600241-excel-vba-close-workbook-after-inactivity.html

Comment: Thanks, wish you posted it as an answer, I'd of given you credit. Although I am getting errors, since I use Option Explicit the code shown won't work as written.

Comment: It also doesn't say where the code goes... :) If you can help tell me where each section goes it be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the link that is in the third post down from what @Head of Catering told you to see.  [Here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/600315-2nd-close-workbook-after-inactivity.html) it is.

Comment: I did, and the link provided has a link which goes to another post which has an excel sheet as a demo which no longer exists.  Sorry it's not as black and white to me as it is obviously to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with the original answer below, I came up with my own, after a little more research.

Once you open the developer's section you will find your sheets, place this code below into ThisWorkbook. That will allow your code to work through the entire sheet. I now it set up where there is a 10:00 minute initial timer, and a 05:00 minute timer if there is activity after the fact. You can change that to whatever you want.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    RunTime
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If EndTime Then
        Application.OnTime _
                EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
                Procedure:="CloseWB", _
                Schedule:=False
        EndTime = Empty
    End If
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    RunTime
End Sub
```

The part below this needs to go into a newly created module, name it whatever you want, mine is called SaveWB

```
Option Explicit

Public EndTime
Sub RunTime()
    Application.OnTime _
            EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
            Procedure:="CloseWB", _
            Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub CloseWB()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

I changed the code from:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    .Save
    .Saved = True
    .Close
End With
```

To what was above it.

```
    With ThisWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    End With
```

The part I created works, the part that was originally posted works in closing but not saving. Do what you will with it, change it as you deem fit, but I am glad I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

This is the information from the link so this question can be used as a reference:

Insert this code as module:

```
' DateTime  : 09/05/2007 08:43
' Author    : Roy Cox (royUK)
' Website   :  Clck here for more examples and Excel Consulting
' Purpose   : Place in a standard module
' Disclaimer; This code is offered as is with no guarantees. You may use it in your
'             projects but please leave this header intact.

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Public EndTime
Sub RunTime()
    Application.OnTime _
            EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
            Procedure:="CloseWB", _
            Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub CloseWB()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Save
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Insert this in 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '--> Set Time Below
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:00")
    RunTime
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If EndTime Then
        Application.OnTime _
        EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
        Procedure:="CloseWB", _
        Schedule:=False
        EndTime = Empty
    End If
    '--> Set Time Below
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:00")
    RunTime
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work though, you are going to have to at least write `Dim EndTime as Long`, etc to get it to work on an Option Explicit sheet won't you? Also aren't we missing the part that will reset itself if someone decided to work in said sheet?

Comment: You are correct, I tested it for closing but did not check for changes being made. Will test again shortly but should probably do some actual work for a bit..

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get in touch with the person who wrote it and see if they can help as well.

Comment: Ok, got in touch with the creator, your code was correct, it turned out to be my computer. It is an old POS, it needs to be restarted to get rid of errors at times. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @MattRidge `Also aren't we missing the part that will reset itself if someone decided to work in said sheet?` No. The end time gets reset in the `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: I'm getting an error with the code above for some reason the CloseWB is being added to the end of the title of the workbook.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Error.Jpg

Comment: Ok, it closes without issue, just doesn't save.

Comment: Posted my own answer, thanks for getting me in the right direction, I just needed to change something to make it work 100%