# Close Workbook if no activity in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I have, it theoretically works. The problem I have is that while I am typing or editing a sheet the worksheet saves and shuts down on me.

So it works, just it doesn't reset the timer while I work in the workbook at all.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    RunTime
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If EndTime Then
        Application.OnTime _
                EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
                Procedure:="CloseWB", _
                Schedule:=False
        EndTime = Empty
    End If
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    RunTime
End Sub
```

Now this is inside ThisWorkbook, figuring that it should encompass everything. Am I missing something? The timer obviously isn't resetting when it should be.

Comment: As far as I remember, it makes it so the code runs, and EndTime is when it is meant to stop.

Comment: yes, hard to debug this code without knowing what this. Is there more code that goes along with this? It's hard to diagnose, because RunTime will not compile as it's written above. Also, you have option explicit set, but you are not declaring your EndTime variable.

Comment: That is the entire code. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: @Scott EndTime is probably a global variable declared in a module somewhere...

Comment: @assylias. I get that, but it may not be, so I wouldn't the user to be aware of it. Probably should have been more clear in direct ask. I seem to be doing that a lot lately... unclear communication!

Comment: Very similar to this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949361/is-there-a-way-through-excel-vba-to-save-and-exit-out-of-a-worksheet-after-a-set/10951264#10951264

Comment: Matt - from above comment `That is the entire code.` No, it wasn't the entire code, and I was trying to explain that! I found the full code based on @AlistairWeir link to your OQ! Hard to help if you can't provide the missing information. I ran your original code and it worked for me. Maybe you are typing /editing a cell during the time that the CloseWB is set to run, only the Workbook_SheetChange event hasn't fired to reset your time because Excel doesn't recognize the event until after you hit Enter and actually change something.

Comment: I completely forgot I asked that... I've been working way too hard.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only reasons why the call to cancel the schedule does not work could be:

- the procedure name is different (CloseWB) or
- EndTime has changed since the task was initially scheduled or
- RunTime does something that makes the workbook close...