# How to refresh pivot table in excel using php

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a file in xls format that I need to refresh (use 'refresh all' button in Excel) once a day and then retrieve the data from the pivot table and inset them into the database (MySQL). The file gets data from an external source (retrieve data from sharepoint 2007).

How is the easiest way to do this? 
I'm thinking abaout PHP but do I not quite know how you go about it. From what I read PHPExcel does not support this operations.
When you try to use COM I get an error:

```
Fatal error: in D:\xampp\htdocs\sp\xls\index.php on line 11
```

And here is a php code:

```
<?php

// Start Excel
$excel = new COM("Excel.Application") or die ("Could not load Excel.Application");

// Make Excel visible.
$excel->Application->Visible = 1; 

// Open  workbook
$Workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open('D:/xampp/htdocs/sp/xls/emails.xls', 'r+') ;

// Refresh all
$Workbook->RefreshAll();

// Save updated excel file out to disk somewhere
$Workbook->SaveAs('D:/xampp/htdocs/sp/xls/emails.xls');

// Close all instances of excel:
$Workbook->Close(false);
unset($Workbook);

$excel->Workbooks->Close();
$excel->Quit();
unset($excel);
?>
```

I'm using windows 7 and xampp with php 5.5.6

In php.ini I've added this line:

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Alternate: is it possible to run *.iqy file generated by sharepoint in php?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my problem.

Instead, refresh the data by PHP pointed out in a query that collects data during the re-launch of the sheet. To this I added [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10955080/1251563) VBA script save changes and close file.

At the end of the added task scheduler to run the sheet once per day. 
The rest of downloading data from Excel using PHPExcel.